# How to get relative path to static string?

Tags: c#, path, static-methods, webmethod

In my Asp.Net page I have one webmethod that sends some data to other page and for this method I have to provide path, something like this:

```
string Path => Server.MapPath(@"\myPath1");

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string GetAvailability()
{
    //xdocDetail = XDocument.Load(Path); //THIS DO NOT WORK, NEEDS STATIC STRING
    xdocDetail = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Eggii\Source\Repos\adm_app3\ADM_App\Content\Xmls\Detail.xml");

    List<DetailList> availabilityList = (from detail in xdocDetail.Descendants("Product")
                                         select new DetailList
                                         {
                                          Detail6 = (string)detail.Element("Availability") ?? "Unknown",
                                         }).ToList();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(availabilityList.Select(x => x.Detail6));
}
```

But I do not want that ugly full path in my method, is it possible somehow to get relative path to this webmethod? Or some other better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content is stored in your project you could use [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains the application root directory in ASP.NET. This will look like:

`xdocDetail = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+Path)`

Comment: But what if content isn't stored in project? @Max Mokrousov

Comment: @Eggii, What do you mean by content isn't stored in the project? Is path relative to something or always hardcoded? If it is always hardcoded there is no way other than store full path. However, I advise storing path in web.config, you will be able to change path without changing the code.